# Launch Activity kept inside jar file in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, jar

In my jar file i have some classes and 1 Activity. I am launching the activity from on of the class files. Code I am using:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, nextActivity.Class());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

mContext is the context of the Activity which is inside application.
And **nextActivity** is the activity which is inside jar file.
I have also mentioned this activity in the manifest of Application.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.nextActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
          >
```

bue the code is crashing. Even I am not getting any errors in Logcat.

Comment: Crashing with no errors in logcat? Clear all filters and try again.

Comment: See [here](http://androhub.com/android-intents/) for proper way to use Intent.